# Is there a good word for vacation?

Tags: vocabulary, modern-life

It occurred to me that I don't know a good Latin word for a vacation.
I don't mean a celebration, or any religious or other public event, but just a period of time I have decided to take off work.
The period can be paid or unpaid, and it might not include any noteworthy activities.
I am not sure if there were vacations in Rome like there are today, and I couldn't find good fits in dictionaries.
It seems that *iustitium* is a break from court activities and *feriae* sounds a bit more like a festival than vacation, but I could be mistaken.
I think I have used *feriae aestivae* in the past to refer to a summer vacation, but I wonder if this is really a good choice.
One obvious translation for "vacation" is *vacatio*, but it does not look that appropriate.
What word(s) would you use for vacation and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, I travel to the [Morgan and Silva Furman University Lexicon](https://ia801000.us.archive.org/12/items/TheLexiconAnglumEtLatinumByDavidMorgan/MorganAndSilvaFurmanUniversityLexicon.pdf) for more modern terms. Of course, a vacation is not necessary a modern invention, but this lexicon attempts to find the earliest forms that match the modern definitions, so here is what I found (Format: translation = literal translation):

> **Vacation**
>
> - *commeatus, -ûs*, m. = voyage/leave
> - *iter recreatorium* = recreational journey*
> - *feriae*, f.pl. = festivals
> - *vacationes*, f.pl. = freedoms
> - *dies feriatae* = days at leisure
>
> **Specific Holidays/Vacations**
>
> - *feriae nataliciae* = Christmas Vacation
> - *feriae aestivae* = Summer Vacation
>
> **Day Off/Vacation Day/Holiday (Job)**
>
> - *dies quieti datus* = day given for rest
> - *dies feriatus* = day at leisure
>
> **Vacation from School**
>
> - *vacatio* = freedom
> - *feriae*
>
> **Vacation (Tourism)**
>
> - *peregrinatio voluptario* = pleasant traveling*
> - *peregrinatio ferialis* = ferial traveling*
> - *peregrinatio curiosa* = careful traveling*

Now, for my comments and interpretation. As you mentioned, there are many types of vacations. From a day off, to traveling abroad, a vacation can be a very malleable term. This is reflected by the options we have here. And I have drawn several conclusions from them.

1. A day (or days) off from school or work for leisure is a *dies feriatus*. This fits well as the adjective *feriatus* means "at leisure" rather than something closer to the traditional definition of *feriae* (festivals). I also like *dies quieti datus* in more of the sense of a day set in advance for the purpose of rest (like a random day off from school).
2. A vacation (usually extended) for a holiday or event is a *feriae* (singular article with a plural noun!). It is then accompanied by an adjective indicating the holiday/festival for which it is (ex: *feriae nataliciae* = Christmas Vacation). This is because these vacations are given for the purpose of celebrating a specific holiday (summer is questionable, but technically fits this).
3. A vacation in which one travels to another place could be a *commeatus*, *iter recreatorium*, *peregrinatio voluptario*, or *peregrinatio ferialis*. This is for the obvious connection they make to the journey aspect of a vacation.

---

*All asterisked terms are of more modern origins, so if you would like to stay classical, try other definitions.

In addition, *iustitium* is a court break/break from daily business **due to a national calamity**, so I don't know what kind of vacations you are taking, but I would avoid this one. I could maybe see it working if it was a day off because of some tragedy that befell the organization, but even that is debatable.